# Docker Store Vs Docker Hub

Tags: security, docker

Did anyone actually figure out the difference between "Docker Store" that Docker introduced at DockerCon2016 and "Docker Hub"?

Is Docker just trying to make a fancy version of Docker hub to have something like Apple Store, Android Store etc? or are there any specific use cases it is trying to solve by introducing this? I think, it can very well use Docker hub for providing trusted, validated etc. enterprise images as it is now providing official images. Then why "Docker Store" ???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main difference is the commercial aspect (as in "revenue stream for Docker"), as pointed out in this [Techcrunch article](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/21/docker-launches-a-new-marketplace-for-containerized-software/?es_p=2041463) from  [Frederic Lardinois (@fredericl)](https://twitter.com/fredericl):

> The idea behind the store is to create a self-service portal for Docker’s ecosystem partners to publish and distribute their software through Docker images — and for users to make it easier to deploy these applications.
>
> While Docker already offered its own registry for containers (DockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/explore/), too, the Docker Store is specifically geared toward the needs of enterprises.
> The store will offer enterprises “with compliant, commercially supported software from trusted and verified publishers, that is packaged as Docker images,” the company says, and feature both free and paid software.
> **Unsurprisingly, Docker will take a cut when a user installs a paid application through the store (though what exactly this revenue share agreement for paid-via-Docker content looks like is currently unclear)**.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. Yeah it seems like a commercial version of Docker Hub. I am still little confused on why do they not actually use existing Docker Hub for this purpose. Docker hub gained enough reputation now (Has bad one too but official images have good rep - not 100% though). Maybe they want to build a new brand or so? We have to wait and see until they release their clear feature set, ideas and release their beta to people.

Comment: @innocentme I agree, I suspect that when you have meme like https://memegenerator.net/instance/65314737, it was urgent to propose to enterprises something more "controlled" than DockerHub ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still don't get it. "Geared towards the needs of enterprises" doesn't make me any the wiser. Is there some kind of service agreement when using the images? If so, why not just incorporate that into hub? Is there an explanation beyond 'because enterprise'?

Answer (score 2):

The other difference is you don't get to see the Docker file that was used to create it. Yes you can reverse engineer it but its not perfect. https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image

Personally I prefer to know what images contain, even if they are "certified" but then the whole payment model fails as soon as you can see the Dockerfile.

Comment: “then the whole payment model fails as soon as you can see the Dockerfile.” Not necessary, for example you can download something that requires credential. You won’t be able to replicate the image simply by knowing the URL.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I read these are the main purposes behind docker store :

> **Our goals with Docker Store are designed around bringing Docker users and ecosystem partners together.**
>
> - Provide a scalable self-service system for ISVs to publish and distribute trusted and enterprise-ready content
> - Provide a publishing process that validates software quality, including; security scanning, component inventory, the open-source
>     license usage and use of best practices in image construction.
> - Provide enterprise users with compliant, commercially supported software from trusted and verified publishers, that is packaged as
>     Docker images.
> - We’ve added powerful search and browsing capabilities, including categorization.

So, I presume it's going to focus on commercial aspects of the app distribution and focus on consumers of the apps (something like [Bitnami](http://www.bitnami.com)), but Docker hub would be for development community.

Reference :

https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-store/